# Differential Equation of Elimination of Arbitrary Constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:
Find the differential Equations having as solution:
Eq.1:    y=xsin(x+c)

Tip: (Elimination of Arbitrary constant)

My Answer:
First Derivative of Equation 1:
By Product Rule

dy/dx = x dy/dx(sin(x+c)) + sin(x+c) dy/dx(x)

dy/dx = xcos(x+c) + sin(x+c) (1)

Eq.2)     dy/dx = xcos(x+c) + sin(x+c)

Hence, how to eliminate the c? Correct my solutions if there is error

Comment: What have you tried already? Please click "Edit" above to improve your post (by telling us more: e.g. your thoughts about this problem, if any.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$ \sin(x+c)=y/x$$ and $$\cos(x+c) = \sqrt {1-\frac {y^2}{x^2}}$$
Via substitution in your $$\frac {dy}{dx}=\sin(x+c)+x\cos (x+c)$$
You get $$\frac {dy}{dx}=y/x +\sqrt {x^2-y^2}$$

Comment: Thank you sir, i'll take note of that.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.